# MySQL: Revenu Report Risers & Fallers, Month over Month

Tags: mysql, join, reporting, revenue

Folks, I've a table that holds Client Revenue by month, example:

Table: ClientRevenueMonthly

```
+-------------+--------------+------------+
| ClientName  |   Revenue    |    Date    |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
| Client A    |  $95,137.68  |  Sep 2019  |
| Client A    |  $67,188.69  |  Oct 2019  |
| Client B    |  $15,741.61  |  Sep 2019  |
| Client B    |  $9,244.99   |  Oct 2019  |
| Client C    |  $22,655.10  |  Sep 2019  |
| Client C    |  $15,804.12  |  Oct 2019  |
| Client D    |  $5,365.97   |   Sep 2019 |
| Client D    |  $13,640.73  |  Oct 2019  |
+-------------+--------------+------------+
```

Here's a create sample:

```
CREATE TABLE ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName VARCHAR(20), Revenue VARCHAR(20), Date VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client A","$30,920.33","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client A","$37,715.16","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client B","$58,141.81","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client B","$75,464.45","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client D","$112,236.17","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client D","$133,554.62","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client E","$146,969.71","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client E","$148,938.93","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client F","$72,501.19","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client F","$133,978.90","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client G","$4,084.18","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client G","$8,278.86","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client H","$1,089,227.80","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client H","$977,230.18","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client I","$56,930.20","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client I","$57,127.94","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client J","$500,675.06","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client J","$539,022.22","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client K","$10,694.43","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client K","$571,525.17","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client L","$784,721.60","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client L","$4,271.42","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client M","$159,789.69","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client M","$174,269.57","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client N","$3,954.68","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client N","$6,015.94","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client O","$82,038.83","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client O","$96,439.68","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client P","$16,805.11","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client P","$9,521.79","2019-10");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client Q","$3,758.47","2019-09");
INSERT INTO ClientRevenueMonthly (ClientName,Revenue,Date) VALUES("Client Q","$5,068.93","2019-10");
```

I need to generate a report that shows the client "risers" and "fallers" month over month, such that those clients which see >=20% change (+ or -) from month to month are represented by client like so (for any given month...here the example shows 'TotalCurrentRev' as representing "Oct" and 'TotalPreviousRev' for "Sep"):

```
+-------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| ClientName  |  Type    |  TotalCurrentRev  |  TotalPreviousRev   |  TotalMoMChange |
+-------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| Client A    |  Riser   |  $95,137.68       |  $67,188.69         |  41.60%         |
| Client B    |  Riser   |  $15,741.61       |  $9,244.99          |  70.27%         |
| Client C    |  Faller  |  $15,804.12       |  $22,655.10         |  -43.35%        |
| Client D    |  Faller  |  $5,365.97        |  $13,640.73         |  -60.66%        |
+-------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

I've been messing around with Joins but can't seem to get this right.  Here is where I'm at:

```
SELECT cr1.clientName as 'Client Name', 
    if(((cr3.revenue / cr2.revenue) * 100) >= 20, 'Riser', 'Faller') as 'Type', 
    cr2.revenue as 'TotalCurrentRev',
    cr3.revenue as 'TotalPreviousRev', 
    ((cr3.revenue / cr2.revenue) * 100) as 'TotalMoMChange'
FROM   ClientRevenueMonthly cr1
JOIN   (
    SELECT clientName, revenue FROM ClientRevenueMonthly GROUP BY clientName
    ) cr2 ON (cr2.clientName = cr1.clientName)
LEFT JOIN  ClientRevenueMonthly cr3 ON 
           (cr3.date = DATE_SUB(cr1.date, INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND cr3.clientName = cr1.clientName)
WHERE      cr1.date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
GROUP BY   cr1.clientName, cr1.date
ORDER BY   cr1.clientName, cr1.date;
```

Any help is greatly apprecieated!

Comment: Thanks!  Made recommended updates

Comment: quick suggestion to your data (if you're able to edit it), if you're only doing month/year-related queries, you can store `Feb 2019` as `2019-02` and it'll naturally sort nicely. It might make dealing with previous/next months easier.

Comment: And for reference, you can use this to simulate queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df7203/1

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones thanks!  Data updated.  pretty flexible there.  Maybe I'm just tired, but I'm having trouble getting past where I'm at with eh current query... maybe I've been looking at it too long.  Thanks too for the sqlfiddle link... I[m playing with that now